# Problem returning form field validation messages

Tags: php, codeigniter

My `updateHunter()` in `HunterController.php` file should make an update of the registration method information and redirect to the listing page if everything is ok, if not, it should return to the update form which will be shown message(s) to correct the problem of a certain field(s).

When returning to the form page `form_update.php` to make the user correct the failed fields I come across the error: **Update Undefined variable $user_hunter**.

[Image here: screen fully white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12BC0.png)

- `form_page.php`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url('css/bootstrap.css'); ?>">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/41b4cd8ba8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" href="<?= base_url('js/bootstrap.js')?>"></script>
        <title>Update <?= $user_hunter['name_hunter'] ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contained">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 mt-2">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4>Update <?= $user_hunter['name_hunter'] ?>
                                <a href="<?= site_url('/home');?>" class="btn btn-secondary float-end"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>&nbsp;Return list</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <?php $validation = \Config\Services::validation(); ?>
                        <form action="<?= site_url('update/'.$user_hunter['id_hunter'])?>" method="POST">
                            <div class="form_group">
                                <div class="form_group">
                                    <div for="name_hunter">ID:
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="id_hunter" value="<?= $user_hunter['id_hunter'] ?>" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="form_group">
                                    <div for="name_hunter">Name:
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_hunter" maxlength="30" value="<?= $user_hunter['name_hunter'] ?>">
                                        <?php if($validation->getError('name_hunter')) {?>
                                            <div class='text-danger mt-1'>
                                                <?= $error = $validation->getError('name_hunter'); ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php }?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                ... (More fiels below)   
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Update</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

- `HunterController.php`

```
    public function updateHunter()
    {
        try {
            helper(['form', 'url', 'html']);
            $validations = $this->validate([
                'name_hunter' => 'required|max_length[30]',
                'year_hunter' => 'required|integer',
                'height_hunter' => 'required|decimal',
                'weight_hunter' => 'required|decimal',
                'type_hunter' => 'required|max_length[30]',
                'type_nen' => 'required|max_length[30]',
                'type_blood' => 'required|max_length[3]'
            ],
            [
                'name_hunter' => [
                    'required' => 'Hunter name can't be empty.',
                    'max_length' => 'Hunter name must be a maximum of 30 characters.'
                ],
                'year_hunter' => [
                    'required' => 'Hunter year can't be empty.',
                    'integer' => 'Hunter age must be a whole number.'
                ],
                'height_hunter' => [
                    'required' => 'Hunter weight can't be empty.',
                    'decimal' => 'Hunter weight must be a decimal number.'
                ],
                'weight_hunter' => [
                    'required' => 'Hunter weight can't be empty.',
                    'decimal' => 'Hunter weight must be a decimal number.'
                ],
                'type_hunter' => [
                    'required' => 'It is necessary to define the type of Hunter.',
                    'max_length' => 'Hunter type must be a maximum of 30 characters.'
                ],
                'type_nen' => [
                    'required' => 'It is necessary to define the type Nen.',
                    'max_length' => 'Nen type must be a maximum of 30 characters.'
                ],
                'typo_blood' => [
                    'required' => 'It is necessary to define the type Blood.',
                    'max_length' => 'Blood type must be a maximum of 30 characters..'
                ]
            ]);
            $hunter = new HunterModel();
            $id_hunter = $this->request->getPost('id_hunter');
            if ($validations) {
                $data = [
                'name_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('name_hunter'),
                'year_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('year_hunter'),
                'height_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('height_hunter'),
                'weight_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('weight_hunter'),
                'type_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('type_hunter'),
                'type_nen' => $this->request->getPost('type_nen'),
                'type_blood' => $this->request->getPost('type_blood')
                ];
                $hunter->update($id_hunter, $data);
                return $this->response->redirect(site_url('/home'));  
            } else {
                echo view('form_update', ['validation' => $this->validator]);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following tutorial:

https://www.guru99.com/codeigniter-form-validation.html#6

Specifically:

Populating Submitted Form Data: Sticky Forms

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

they is no user_hunter var passed to form_update view, nor in updateHunter()